# recurrence relation roots

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

i have a recurrence relation $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ with the inital conditions $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$

From this, i know the characteristic equation is: $x^2 - 2x -1$
however this poses a problem because the roots are not whole numbers, rather, they are $1 + \sqrt{2}$  and $1 - \sqrt{2}$. Is there another way to solve these sorts of recurrence relations? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a typo in the equation? or is it $a_n = 3a_{n - 1}$?

Comment: `this poses a problem because the roots are not whole numbers` What is the problem with that?

Comment: Do you mean $a_n = 2a_{n-1} +a_{n-2}$, OP?

Comment: sorry that was a typo yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = c_1 (1+\sqrt{2})^n + c_2 (1-\sqrt{2})^n$. We then have

$$c_1 (1+\sqrt{2})^0 + c_2 (1-\sqrt{2})^0 = c_1 + c_2 = 0$$
$$c_1 (1+\sqrt{2})^1 + c_2 (1-\sqrt{2})^1 = c_1 (1+\sqrt{2}) + c_2 (1-\sqrt{2})= 1$$

So $c_1 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ and $c_2 = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. So then

$$
a_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} (1+\sqrt{2})^n - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(1-\sqrt{2})^n
$$

Try it for yourself and plug in values of $n$. Even though the roots of characteristic were irrational, you will get integer values. (Even better, can you think of a *proof* that $a_n$ will always be an integer.)